# How to find out Total Space and Used space in One Drive Account (IOS Sdk)?

Tags: live-sdk, onedrive

I am using OneDrive ios sdk in my app. I need to show the total space and used space in one of my screen. How can I use LiveConnectionClient api to fetch these details?

Comment: The question is tagged with onedrive-api, Was OneDrive REST API call sufficing your need considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer. Call this

`[self.liveClient getWithPath:@"me/skydrive/quota" delegate:self userState:@"getQuota"];`

Comment: can you write it in more detail? like where you get response? which delegate need to implement?

Comment: i want to implement search functionality..if you did it please reply